# Why doesn't Tony Stark lose a leg?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-3

In *Iron Man 3* (2013), Aldrich Killian seems to manage to cut off Tony Stark's leg during a fight scene. However, when Stark emerges from the suit mere frames later he is physically fine. Why wasn't his leg missing after this occurrence?

Comment: I noticed that too and figured it was probably a bad job of editing the shots with Tony jumping in and out of suits.

Comment: Joker is right. I replayed that scene over and over. At the end the suit is cut in half and Stark appears out of it. There is also a few pictures when he feels pain in the suit when Killian is holding him. So for the sake of consistency and continuity this is an error. He should have lost a leg.

Comment: Thanks to his days as a promiscuous bachelor, Tony has mastered both front and rear entry, as well as pulling out just in time. These skills allowed him to jump suits and save his leg.

Answer (score 31):

If you watch the scene in slo-mo, you can see him remove his leg from the Iron Man suit a few frames before Killian chops it off.

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @jo1storm - it should indeed.

Answer (score 17):

In the end fight, it does show (in slow motion) Tony ejecting his leg from the right Iron Man leg right before Killian chops it with his hand. But I'm pretty sure that the leg doesn't actually attach that way. Doesn't it work more like a sheath and not a greave?

Comment: If you want the suits being put on and taken off in The Avengers it looks like each version is put on slightly differently.

Comment: The whole fight with Killian is Tony hopping into and out of suits to avoid getting killed.  This was one example of that.

Comment: In many of the suits he jumped into during that scene, he was entering from the back. This would imply that he could exit from the rear as well. I just don't remember if the suit in question was entered this way.

Comment: If you watch it in slow motion, it looks like he only cuts the front portion of it off instead of the whole leg. It would still be a pretty good chunk of armor, but if Tony's leg is toward the back, it wouldn't cut into him.

Comment: @SocioMatt One or two of the suits, Tony entered through the back and exited through the front.  The modular ones are especially flexible like that..

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to see this - it gets out of frame rather quickly - but Tony pulls his leg out and it then cuts to the shot that shows Tony's leg sans armor.